# Fetch the message sent by the bot before restarting the session

Tags: discord.py

I know that I can get a message object using `await ctx.fetch_message(mesId)`. Although If I send a message, and then start the bot's session (Restart the Client). The script cannot see the message. Is there any way to get rid of this problem?

Also, it's worth mentioning that I use `discord.Bot` type user not `discord.Client`

Comment: wdym by `start bot's session`?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I mean when you send message, befor you start your program It can't read it. Same if you send message during one session, then restart your program - it won't be able to read it

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no `ctx.fetch_message` [ref](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command_completion#discord.ext.commands.Context)

It should be `ctx.channel.fetch_message` Keep in mind you can get another channel by using `await bot.get_channel(ID)` and then fetch the message.

Your code should look like this:

```py
# using another channel 
channel = await bot.get_channel(123456)
message = await channel.fetch_message(123456)

# or using ctx
message = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(123456)
```

[Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch_message#discord.TextChannel.fetch_message)